# write permission to a folder

Tags: permissions, directory

I have the following folder:

```
$ ls -ahl /mnt/smrtanalysis/
total 16K
drwxr-xr-x  4 smrtanalysis smrtanalysis 4.0K Jul 25 01:52 .
drwxr-xr-x  6 root         root         4.0K Jul 25 01:46 ..
lrwxrwxrwx  1 smrtanalysis smrtanalysis   13 Jul 25 01:52 admin -> current/admin
lrwxrwxrwx  1 smrtanalysis smrtanalysis   33 Jul 25 01:48 current -> install/smrtanalysis_2.3.0.140936
drwxrwxr-x  4 smrtanalysis smrtanalysis 4.0K Jul 25 01:48 install
lrwxrwxrwx  1 smrtanalysis smrtanalysis   16 Jul 25 01:52 smrtcmds -> current/smrtcmds
lrwxrwxrwx  1 smrtanalysis smrtanalysis   17 Jul 25 01:52 tmpdir -> /tmp/smrtanalysis
drwxrwxr-x 13 smrtanalysis smrtanalysis 4.0K Jul 25 01:52 user data
```

and I would like as user (`ubuntu`) to be able to write to it:

```
ubuntu@waterhouse-1:~$ groups
ubuntu smrtanalysis
```

`ubuntu` user is in group `smrtanalysis`, but I still not able to write into `/mnt/smrtanalysis/`

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Permissions]

You have `755 (rwxr-xr-x)` on the dir `/mnt/smrtanalysis/`, shown as `.` in the `ls` output, with `owner:group` of `smrtanalysis:smrtanalysis`. ubuntu is part of group `smrtanalysis` but group only has `r-x` you need to `sudo chmod g+w /mnt/smrtanalysis/` to give the group write access.

Comment: Thank you it works. Is it possible that when `ubuntu` user copies the files to `/mnt/smrtanalysis/` the files get own by `smrtanalysis: smrtanalysis` rather than `ubuntu:ubuntu`?